# Click-Once Deployment Overwriting User Settings

Tags: .net, vb.net, deployment, settings

Click-once deployments are suppose to maintain user settings, but on this one application we have the user settings are overwritten to the Visual Studio default every time we publish an update. Any ideas of what might be happening?

Comment: The *user* settings?  Or is it really the app settings?  Or is it really the user settings going back to their default values?

Comment: Yes, it's really user settings not app settings.  And yes, you are correct going back to default values.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen when you make a change to the structure of the settings/config file.

If you publish an update w/out changing the structure of the file the settings on end user's machines should be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [ClickOnce and ApplicationSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228995.aspx).
I guess you are in the case:

*Setting's default changed; local setting still set to original default in user.config ->
The setting is merged into the current version's user.config with the new default as the value*